# Slow response when writing value to characteristic for BLE (Objective C)

Tags: objective-c, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth

I'm trying to update a characteristic on a BLE device using Objective C and CoreBluetooth. It works (the write causes a LED to turn on on the device, so I can see when the update occurs), but the delay between writing the value and the response on the device is around 15-25 seconds (!).

I am writing the value using:

```
[peripheral writeValue:data forCharacteristic:characteristic type:CBCharacteristicWriteWithResponse];
```

and I get the callback for `didWriteValueForCharacteristic` 15+ seconds later.

I have noticed that this seems to be something to do with the way I am storing the `CBPeripheral` object. I think this because if I try to write to the device directly from one of the callback functions in `CBPeripheralDelegate` (e.g. `didDiscoverCharacteristicsForService`), which passes the peripheral as an argument, then the response from the device is instant. The long delays only occur if I try to write values to the peripheral using my stored version.

I have tried storing the peripheral as a property, in an array and I have tried performing the write via a queue using `dispatch_async` (as the action to write the value comes from a user interface action in a C++ program).

Do you have any thoughts or suggestions as to why I am experiencing these problems?

Thanks,
Adam

p.s. the device I am trying to write to is a micro:bit

Comment: If you use LightBlue.app (it's available on the AppStore), does it take that much time? This could check if the issue is on the iPhone code or the BLE device one.

Comment: Yes, I tried this and the LightBlue app seems to cause an instant response on the device. So it must be something in my code. I don't understand what is causing the delay between my call to `writeValue` and the response from `didWriteValueForCharacteristic`. I seem to have no control over this...

Comment: You might be blocking your current thread, but we can’t guess what’s wrong

Comment: Hmm, yes, I am suspecting something like this. I found a clue - if the peripheral is provided to me in a callback function (e.g. in `didDiscoverCharacteristicsForService`) and I call my function to write to the characteristic on the device, this works immediately with no delay. If I store the peripheral and try to call it from elsewhere, then I get the 15-20 second delay. Any tips on how to make sure I'm not blocking here?

Comment: I am performing my action on a dispatch queue... `dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue (DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0);` - perhaps this is the wrong thing to do?

Comment: I have now amended the question to be more specific on the problem